# Enemy Projectiles Aren't Appending On Screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have here my script that targets the player what ever position he is at but the projectiles aren't  showing on my screen [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/f01c98dee799b5037fa6279777025dc1). He isn't attacking at all, I don't know why. I am in my main loop I draw the bullets to.

my enemy bullet class

```
    # enemys bullets
    ksud = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
    class Boolss(object):
       def __init__(self, x, y,color, xspeed, yspeed):
           self.x = x
           self.y = y
           self.xspeed = xspeed
           self.yspeed = yspeed
           self.ksud = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
           self.hitbox  = self.ksud.get_rect()
           self.rect  = self.ksud.get_rect()
           self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
           self.speed = 10
           self.color = color
           self.hitbox = (self.x + 57, self.y + 33, 29, 52) # NEW
       def draw(self, window):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            player_rect = self.ksud.get_rect(center = self.rect.center) 
            player_rect.centerx += 0 # 10 is just an example
            player_rect.centery += 0 # 15 is just an example
            window.blit(self.ksud, player_rect)
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 97, self.y + 33, 10, 10) # NEW
            window.blit(self.ksud,self.rect)
```

this goes on my main loop, it appends bullets and targets the player

```
            for shootss in shootsright:
                
                shootss.x += shootss.xspeed
                shootss.y += shootss.yspeed
                if shootss.x > 500 or shootss.x < 0 or shootss.y > 500 or shootss.y < 0:
                    shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))


                if len(shootsright) < 2:
                    
                    start_x = round(enemyshoots1.x+enemyshoots1.width-107)
                    start_y = round(enemyshoots1.y + enemyshoots1.height-50)
                    target_x = playerman.x+playerman.width//2
                    target_y = playerman.y+playerman.width//2
                    dir_x, dir_y = target_x - start_x, target_y - start_y
                    distance = math.sqrt(dir_x**2 + dir_y**2)
                    if distance > 0:
                        shootsright.append(Boolss(start_x,start_y,(0,0,0),dir_x, dir_y))
```

I draw the bullets that are appending on my screen but they don't show

```
            for shootss in shootsright:
                shootss.draw(window)
```

my full code [script](https://pastebin.com/DEAT4PaQ)

Comment: where do you use `shootss.draw(window)` in loop ? Do you do it after `fill()` and before `update()` ? You can also use `print()` to see if this part of code is executed - maybe you run in place which is never executed.

Comment: BTW: you could use `for`-loop to load image - and then you can have all in one line - ie. `self.rights = [pygame.image.load("L{}.png".format(number)) for number in range(1, 16)]`

Comment: maybe first check `print(shootsright)` in different places - maybe this list is empty.

Comment: you create `shootsright = []` and you append iitems in `for shootss in shootsright:` but if `shootsright:` is empty then it will nevere execute `for shootss in shootsright:` so it will not run `shootsright.append()`. There is something from with your idea. OR maybe you have wrong indentation and this part of code should be outside `for shootss in shootsright:`

Comment: BTW: in Python it is not good idea to remove item from iterated list `for ... in list: list.pop(...)` because when you remove item then other items moves in free place but `for` doesn't know it and in next loop it skip one element - and this way it doesn't check it and it keep element which it should remove. Better duplicate list `for ... in list.copy(): list.pop(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enemy Projectiles Attack Way To Fast Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433686/enemy-projectiles-attack-way-to-fast-problem)

Comment: Please don't post twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433686/enemy-projectiles-attack-way-to-fast-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't run code but I think you have wrong indentations and this make problem.

You append to shootsright` inside

```
  for shootss in shootsright:

      shootsright.append(...)
```

but at start `shootsright` is empty so it never runs `for shootss in shootsright:` and it never runs `shootsright.append()` - so `shootsright` is always empty.

Probably you have to move it outside this loop (you have to change indentations)

```
  for shootss in shootsright:

        shootss.x += shootss.xspeed
        shootss.y += shootss.yspeed
        if shootss.x > 500 or shootss.x < 0 or shootss.y > 500 or shootss.y < 0:
            shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))


  # outside `for`-loop

  if len(shootsright) < 2:

        start_x = round(enemyshoots1.x+enemyshoots1.width-107)
        start_y = round(enemyshoots1.y + enemyshoots1.height-50)
        target_x = playerman.x+playerman.width//2
        target_y = playerman.y+playerman.width//2
        dir_x, dir_y = target_x - start_x, target_y - start_y
        distance = math.sqrt(dir_x**2 + dir_y**2)
        if distance > 0:
            shootsright.append(Boolss(start_x,start_y,(0,0,0),dir_x, dir_y))
```

---

**BTW:** next time you can use `print()` in many places to see values in this list in different moments and to see which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`.