# Enemy Projectiles Attack Way To Fast Problem

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make my enemy bullets attack the player
but its attacking way to fast I dont know why [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/bd9d51db8258bc860ca87df6f3338103)
my enemy bullets class

```
    # enemys bullets
    ksud = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
    class Boolss(object):
       def __init__(self, x, y,color, xspeed, yspeed):
           self.x = x
           self.y = y
           self.xspeed = xspeed
           self.yspeed = yspeed
           self.ksud = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
           self.hitbox  = self.ksud.get_rect()
           self.rect  = self.ksud.get_rect()
           self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
           self.color = color
           self.hitbox = (self.x + 57, self.y + 33, 29, 52) # NEW
       def draw(self, window):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            player_rect = self.ksud.get_rect(center = self.rect.center) 
            player_rect.centerx += 0 # 10 is just an example
            player_rect.centery += 0 # 15 is just an example
            window.blit(self.ksud, player_rect)
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 97, self.y + 33, 10, 10) # NEW
            window.blit(self.ksud,self.rect)
```

this is where it appends bullet like attack the player

```
          for shootss in shootsright:


                shootss.x += shootss.xspeed
                shootss.y += shootss.yspeed
                if shootss.x > 500 or shootss.x < 0 or shootss.y > 500 or shootss.y < 0:
                    shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))




            if len(shootsright) < 1:
                start_x = round(enemyshoots1.x+enemyshoots1.width-107)
                start_y = round(enemyshoots1.y + enemyshoots1.height-50)
                target_x = playerman.x+playerman.width//2
                target_y = playerman.y+playerman.width//2
                dir_x, dir_y = target_x - start_x, target_y - start_y
                distance = math.sqrt(dir_x**2 + dir_y**2)
                if distance > 0:
                    shootsright.append(Boolss(start_x,start_y,(0,0,0),dir_x, dir_y))
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please don't post twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62420037/enemy-projectiles-arent-appending-on-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
start_x = round(enemyshoots1.x+enemyshoots1.width-107)
start_y = round(enemyshoots1.y + enemyshoots1.height-50)
target_x = playerman.x+playerman.width//2
target_y = playerman.y+playerman.width//2
dir_x, dir_y = target_x - start_x, target_y - start_y
```

If you print the `dir_x` and `dir_y` you'll see that the values are very high. You probably add this values each frame to the position of the bullet. That's why they leave the screen before you can really see them.

You could try this:

```
BULLET_SPEED = 5

delta_x, delta_y = target_x - start_x, target_y - start_y
distance = math.sqrt(delta_x ** 2 + delta_y ** 2)
dir_x = BULLET_SPEED * delta_x / distance
dir_y = BULLET_SPEED * delta_y / distance
```

Consider that this solution doesn't rounds the values and pygame might throw an exception because of coordinates with float values. You should round the coordinates before using them for drawing.

Comment: could you help me with that

Comment: I made a mistake... constants won't help you but the edit above should help

Comment: @HabibIsmail A better approach than dividing by a random constant would be to determine how fast the bullet should be going (in a constant for the code like `BULLET_SPEED=10`). Then portioning that speed between the x and y direction using the ratio of dir_x and dir_y to the length of their hypotenuse. Then no matter which direction/angle it fires it will progress at that defined speed along that angle.

Comment: Sorry, you're completely right... I edited my answer. :)